# How is access to the UI thread handled in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

How is access to the UI thread handled in C#?

why is the UI thread treated differently from other threads?

thank you guys for your help

really appreciate it !

Comment: Really? A search for ".NET UI Thread" yields 34 pages of results and you have to start a new question?

Comment: haha, its funny cause its true

Comment: but non of them answered my question thats why I started a new one ... I looked at every single one of them ... :)

Comment: @CMerat: I'm pretty new, but I'm pretty sure that your comment is a tad offensive.

Answer (score 9):

The UI thread contains the Windows Message Pump.  This makes it critical to keep this thread from being blocked by long running operations.

Typically, that means pushing anything long running onto a separate thread, and then using Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke (Windows Forms) or Dispatcher.Invoke/BeginInvoke (WPF) to pass delegates from other threads in order to update the UI.

Comment: It's also worth noting that very little of the GUI system is thread safe, hence why all the GUI processing must be done on the GUI thread.